# how to get rid of default apache page "it works!"?

Tags: php, apache, mamp-pro

I created a virtual host on MAMP PRO 5 like this "mywebsite.test"   but it does not open the local site unless I add :8888 so it has to be like this "mywebsite.test:8888" then I changed the Apache port to 80 and whenever I try to get them to local site using "mywebsite.test"  is show me the default page of apache "it works!" instead.

I did uncomment this line

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

in

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

but still not working
any solution?

Comment: Find index.html and replace it. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655966/mamp-where-is-localhosts-index-html

Comment: thank you now it show "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server." when trying to access it using mysite.test

Comment: I don't get it why this is downvoted

Comment: Are you using different document root for Virtual host 8888?

Comment: It is downvoted because it is a very basic question.  Search for tutorials on how to install Apache, it will show you how to setup a basic page.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html.

Comment: Your Apache content files are here: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Preferences/Web-Server/.  MAMP provides a nice interface for installation and basic setup, but underneath you have to configure the products themselves.

Comment: @Pandurang I don't know what you mean by that but I have multiple sites and I put them under htdocs folder then I am trying to point to each of them with a virtual host

Comment: This question is not basic MAMP PRO 4 use to work fine but since I upgraded to MAMP PRO 5 I start getting this weird behaviour I have seen other people having same issue too, I am no new to doing this to call myself as a beginner but this is a legit problem I could not find a solution to it

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution this could be helpful to anyone facing this same problem. 
After contacting the support they told me to check indexes under Apache tab and it works

[image]

make sure the Apache port is at 80 and not 8888

[image]